# Find latitude and longitude using City and State columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, data-processing

I have a column with 'CITY' and 'STATE' strings. I tried using geocoder from geopy library to calculate Latitude and Longitude but it timeouts as it exceeds the number of requests also there are about 85895 rows in the data set. So I did value count for the 'CITY_STATE' column and there are 1340 values. Is there a way I can find Latitude and Longitude for those 1340 values and then map those values with the corresponding 'CITY' and 'STATE'.

```
from opencage.geocoder import OpenCageGeocode
key = 'my_key'  # get api key from : https://opencagedata.com
geocoder = OpenCageGeocode(key)
list_lat = []   # create empty lists

list_long = []
for index, row in train.iterrows(): # iterate over rows in dataframe



City = row['CITY']
State = row['STATE']       
query = str(City)+','+str(State)

results = geocoder.geocode(query)   
lat = results[0]['geometry']['lat']
long = results[0]['geometry']['lng']

list_lat.append(lat)
list_long.append(long)

# create new columns from lists    

train['lat'] = list_lat   

test['lon'] = list_long
```

Comment: Can you add your code to question?

Comment: you can add a delay between requests to prevent timeouts using [this](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.16.0/#usage-with-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with custom function and joined both columns to Series `s`:

```
s = train['CITY'].astype(str) + ', ' + train['STATE'].astype(str)

def func(x):
    results = geocoder.geocode(x.name) 
    x['lat'] = results[0]['geometry']['lat']
    x['lon'] = results[0]['geometry']['lng']
    return x

train = train.groupby(s).apply(func)
```

Comment: This method works really fast. But I got a error stating " 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'latitude' ". There is no missing value why does it shows that error? Thank you.

Comment: @GunjanPatait - There are no missing values or `None`s in input data? How working if remove possible missing rows by `train = train.dropna(subset=['CITY','STATE'])` before `s = train['CITY'].astype(str) + ', ' + train['STATE'].astype(str)` ?

Comment: Dataset shape before and after using train = train.dropna(subset=['CITY','STATE']). I still dont understand why is it throwing that error?

Comment: @GunjanPatait - What is `Dataset shape before and after` ? There is difference?

Comment: I'm sorry not to mention. Its the same before and after dropping missing values.

Comment: @GunjanPatait - Not idea, I want tet more, but unfortunately I got `NotAuthorizedError: Your API key is not authorized. You may have entered it incorrectly.` with `db928966954b425ca7d8c56e1f815c60` code. So not idea what is wrong. If possible, can you send me your key (if test key) to my eamil form my profile for testing?